# matching this html element in regex? (without lazy matching!)

Tags: html, regex

I'd like to match everything between   tags.

what's the regex to do that?

A bit like

```
  <tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>
```

But I'd like to not use lazy evaluation.

I want to match each   pair like the regex above, but not using lazy evaluation.

Comment: so, don't! what is your question?

Comment: @SilentGhost what don't you understand?

Comment: what problem do you have not using lazy evaluation?

Comment: don't use regex for html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @SilentGhost I just want to not use lazy evaluation.

Comment: With lazy evaluation it works so using it to match html in this case of matching <tr></tr> tags is fine. without a parser being necessary. I just want to do it without lazy eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching lazily, you could use a negative lookahead (if your flavour supports that). Your example would translate to

```
 <tr[^>]*>((?!</tr>).)*</tr>
```

Of course, you should actually not use regex to parse HTML, as you might have guessed from the comments to your question. =) These expressions may fail horribly on nested tags, comments, and javascript.

Comment: that is really an excellent use of negative lookahead - quite inspiring!.. is there any particular article or part of a book that inspired "((?!abc).)*?" and good closing paragraph too.

Comment: @barlop: Thanks! I think regular-expression.info is the source to go to for all things regex.